# Efficient algorithm for n to m mapping between two data sets

Tags: java, algorithm, mapreduce, combinatorics

I have 3 dynamic sets of elements on one side. e.g.

```
a = [101,102,104] //possible values 101 to 115
b = [201,202] //possible values 201 to 210
c = [301,302,303,304] //possible values 301 to 305
```

I generate all combinations of these 3 sets e.g.

```
setA = ["101|201|301,303", "101,104|202|304", "101,104|202|301,304", ...]
```

a,b,c are out of picture at this point. Now I want to match all elements of setA against another set setB which has only one element from each category. e.g.

```
setB = ["101|202|304","104|202|301" ,"102|202|303", ...]
```

There's an n to m mapping between `setA` and `setB`. i.e One combination from setA can have multiple match in setB and vice versa.

Matching criteria: for any element of setB (e.g."101|202|304") if all of its parts (101,202,304) are contained in some combinations of setA (e.g. "101,104|202|304", "101,104|202|301,304") then consider it a match. so in this example "101|202|304" is said to have a match with both "101,104|202|304" and "101,104|202|301,304"

Currently I have O(n^2) time and O(n) space algorithm but I am really looking for some improvements as this calculation repeats for many such sets. (It's actually a reducer task of a hadoop map-reduce where I generate all combinations of dimensions and aggregate measures that qualifies for given combination). Any framework level optimization is welcome too. e.g. breaking down job in multiple-jobs.

Comment: Your sets are not the same size, in your example, so "n to n" mapping is not correct.  Please give a complete example of an example input and example desired output.

Comment: added matching criteria. hope that explains the problem. if not let me know and I'll try to reitereate.  by "n to n" I simply meant many-to-many relation.

Comment: @RexKerr now you understand the problem can you remove ur downvote? I am still working on your solution btw.

Comment: I never downvoted; I generally first give people a chance to improve the question.  Others are less patient.

Comment: whoever downvoted add comments on how can i improve. I have already edited question now couple of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through `B` and pick out all the first elements you have, turning them back into a set.  For each element of that set, make a map from that element to everything in B that starts with that element.  Now you have a map: `firstElement -> subsetOfBStartingWithThat`.

Now do the same for the subset and second elements, etc. until you have a series of maps

`firstElement -> secondElement -> thirdElement -> ... -> entry in B`.

Now you run through each entry in `A`, and use the maps to tell whether anything is there.  If yes, add it to a set.  If no, leave it empty.  Use this to build a map from elements of A to sets of elements of B.

Then reverse the process by making a map from B to sets of A by iterating through your A -> B map and adding the pair in the opposite orientation.

You have `O(m)` space to create the B-lookup-map, and you'll spend `O(m+n)` time doing the scanning since set lookup is linear.  Building the final lookup sets will take space (and time) proportional to `m * n/2^k` where `k` is the number of separate sets (3 in your case).  There's no way to avoid that: this is actually how many links there are.  (To see why, note that each element of each source set can be viewed as a bit that is either on or off, and you require that the bit be on.  That happens only `1/2^k`th of the time, which is 1/8 in your case.

So you're pretty much stuck at an `n^2` step.  It's inherent in the problem unless you don't need to be comprehensive.  If not, you can use the scheme I outlined above to find *a* match much less expensively.

Comment: your approach gave me another idea. there may be some problem with it but I posted it as another answer here if you care to verify

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different solution than Rex Kerr. First, I created a mapB from setB elements. Each element entirely represent a key and values associated are different measures in my use case.
Then, I iterated each sub element of setA. Created 3 sublists from each element and iterated each sublist in a way to for a key (3 nested for loops). I looked up for that key in mapB. If found I counted mapB values towards this combination. So at end of the all iterations I have aggregated values from setB which qualifies for given combination of setA. That's it. Let me know if anyone want me to be more detailed on this. 
ps - my jobs are running 4 time faster with this changes(2 hours from 7 hours)

Answer (score -1):

The question is not clear, but if I understood correctly, I would solve it this way:

- setA does not exist for me.
- a, b, and c are out of the picture too.

I first pick a common element in "setB" (202 in your example), and for the rest of elements (101, 102, 104, 201, 301, 302, etc.) I would iterate 4 states for each of them:

- 0 = it's not in setB
- 1 = it's in first "entry" of setB
- 2 = it's in second "entry" of setB
- 3 = it's in both entries of setB

I am assuming setB has 2 "entries" always.

Comment: Added some more clarification based on your comment. a,b,c are out of picture but setA is not. it's a join between setA and setB based on matching criteria. setB can have any number of entries.

Comment: what is the problem do you want to solve? ... count how many matches are there? ...or... to list them? ... or what?

Comment: If you read end of question it says "aggregate measures that qualifies for given combination". element of setB is actually key to various mesaures like salesamount, itemcount etc.

Comment: down voting cause i think you are totally heading in wrong direction if you edit or remove your answer based on my updates on question i'll reconsider.